# Why is the role of the file mounted by docker nobody

Tags: docker

I mounted /var/run/docker.sock under the non-root user, and checked that the permission role was nobody. Why not the default root

The mount code is as follows

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint='' -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock controller:v1 bash
bash-5.0# ls /var/run/ -lh
total 0
srw-rw----    1 nobody   nobody         0 Feb  3 07:48 docker.sock
```

At this time, docker daemon cannot be connected by running docker command

```
bash-5.0# docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

> I have granted the non-root user Docker permission with `sudo usermod-ag Docker your-user`

I hope to use Docker CLI in docker container to perform some operations, such as `Docker Run, Docker Ps, Docker images and so on`

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question ? What do you want to solve here....a nobody user is the default when you run a container on from a non root user....what do you exactly expect ?

Comment: Sorry, I have modified my requirements

Comment: Do you have user namespaces configured?

Do these files exist on your computer: `/etc/subuid`, `/etc/docker/daemon.json`? Could you please show their content? I mean "userns-remap" field of `daemon.json`.

Try to run your container with `--userns=host` flag, please tell if it gives any difference for `docker.sock` ownership in the container.

Comment: @chivorotkiv I don't have access to `/etc/docker/ daemon.json`, Is this the reason nobody and nogroup?